# What is the image of $\mathcal{F}$ in $\mathbf{R}$ under the map that takes $f(x)$ in $\mathcal{F}$ to $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x) dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the subset of real valued continuous functions $f(x)$ on $[-1, 1]$ such that $f(x) \geq 0$ (for all $x$ in $[-1, 1]$) and $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)^{n}dx <\infty$. What is the image of $\mathcal{F}$ in $\mathbf{R}$ under the map that takes
$f(x)$ in $\mathcal{F}$ to $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x) dx$?

My Attempt: I think $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)^{n}dx <\infty$ implies $f(x)\leq 1$. Is this correct approach? Otherwise give some hints.

Comment: If $f(x)>1$ for some $x$, you can show that $\limsup \int f^n dx = \infty$. This uses the fact that $f(x)\geq 0$, and isn't hard to prove. How would you approach proving this?

Comment: Thank you, Yes I make it using continuity.

Comment: Exactly. This will allow you to conclude that the image is the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: image is the interval [0,2]

Comment: I was thinking of $\int_0^1$, and I made a mistake, but indeed the image is $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 2):

if $f(a) >1$ for some $a$ then there eixst $r>0$ and $s>1$ such that $f(x)\geq s$ for $a-r\leq x\leq a+r$. This implies that $\int_0^{1}f^{n} \geq s^{n}2r$ so the hypothesis fails. Hence $f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$ and $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx\leq 2$. The answer is $[0,2]$. [Consider the case $f \equiv c$ with $0 \leq c\leq 1$ to see that every number between $0$ and $2$ is in the image].